# Azure Pipeline net6 Projects - NuGet Restore saying error NU1201 not compatible with net5

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I've been going round in circles on this all day. I'm trying to set up my first release pipeline but can't even get the build to work!

Project is a net6 upgraded from the original net5 template. Global.json targets 6.0.300. All projects in the sln have a target framework of net6.

I'm getting an error on the nuget restore step saying "error NU1201: Project My.Project is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Project My.Project supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)"

and then the actual reported error is:
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions.

Local build works great.

The yaml up to the failing restore is:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2022

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
  
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 6.0.300
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: Use NuGet 6.x
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '6.x'
    checkLatest: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: NuGet Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'hidden'
```

I've tried with the windows-latest pool and also tried with the UseDotNet@2 and NuGetToolInstaller@1 the other way round.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another task for NuGet restore which is having  below set of configuration. Please remove your existing restore task and add it.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: NuGet restore
  inputs:
      solution: $(BuildParameters.solution)
```

[image]

I guess the task that you added, not pointing the updated version of netcore version